# Can't create PyObject from integer

Tags: python, c, extend, python-c-api

In writing a Python **extension** in C, I'm just trying to test some things out but realized that I can't build `PyObject*`s from a C `int`. Here a compilable code snippet that demonstrates the problem (you may have to `#include <Python.h>` if not on a Mac),

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
int main(){
    PyObject* obj = Py_BuildValue("i", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

But this results in `Segmentation fault: 11`. Based on Xcode's LLDB it looks like something is wrong when calling `PyInt_FromLong`?

If I try to do the same but using a `double`,

```
PyObject* obj = Py_BuildValue("d", 42.0);
```

It works just fine... I can't find anything online and am out of ideas - any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Could you come up with a minimal *complete* example that demonstrates the problem, and post that?

Comment: @NPE The code is just setting up main but I'll post it anyway

Comment: Are you trying to embed Python in another application?  Write an extension module for Python?  With just that `main` snippet, you're missing the whole Python runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to embed Python in a C program, you first have to initialize Python with `Py_Initialize()`, and you should call `Py_Finalize()` when you're done.

Try this...

```
#include <Python/Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* obj = Py_BuildValue("i", 42);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

...and check out the [embedding docs](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) for some more examples.

Comment: I don't want to embed the interpreter in the C code. I just want to do the same thing I'm able to do using `Py_BuildValue` with `"d"`, `"s"`, etc.

Comment: @Jared: The reason that the "integer" fails while "double" works is probably because integers use a cache of prebuilt small integers, and the cache is built from `Py_Initialize` Doubles don't have such a cache, so it works... by chance.

Comment: @Jared If you're calling `Py_BuildValue()` in C code which isn't an extension module then, by definition, you're embedding Python in C.